# What happens if I get caught hacking?

Tags: warframe

On Corpus terminals, I'm not exactly sure what triggers it, but about a few seconds into hacking a red message displaying the words "INTRUSION DETECTED" flares up.

[image]

To date, I haven't seen any sort of change happen whether or not the hack was completed before the message pops up.  The stats don't suggest there are two categories of hacks which is what some players have been saying.  The affinity gain from hacking is still the same. The timer just keeps on ticking down as normal, and doesn't drain any faster.

What exactly happens when I get an INTRUSION DETECTED message? How do I get the message? Is it a timer based system?  Are there any hidden penalties I might get if I see the message before I finish hacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a practical effect of avoiding that message. If you're unsafe about a hacking puzzle, you can quickly press the use button again to **exit the interaction** (maybe ESC works as well, or that's the button you should use) and you'll **not be penalized** for not correctly solving.

If you **can't solve** the puzzle **after the red message appears**, or if you **exit the interaction** as mentioned, you'll raise an alert.

This possibility may not exist in Sortie missions, since they are like "hard+" missions concerning hacking where cyphers can't be used for Spy missions and you get shocked if you fail.

Answer (score 3):

> When you start rotating the 3rd tile on Corpus consoles, the
>   'INTRUSION DETECTED' alert will appear. Currently it is almost
>   impossible to solve the Hacker Challenge without it (the use of
>   ciphers will prevent the 'INTRUSION DETECTED' alert from appearing).
>   This effect will make time go twice as fast.
>
> 'INTRUSION DETECTED' can only be avoided if a Hacker Challenge only
>   consists of two nodes, and both can be oriented correctly with only
>   one click; orienting the second node will solve the hack without
>   displaying the message. There is no practical effect to avoiding
>   'INTRUSION DETECTED' in this manner.

[source](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Hacking)